# How to preserve Dataset's pagination inside Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, dataset

I'm having troubles preserving automatic pagination provided by `Dataset` when it is embedded in a `Manipulate`.

Consider the following toy dataset:

```
data = Dataset[
  Table[<|"a" -> RandomInteger[10], "b" -> RandomInteger[20], 
    "c" -> RandomChoice[Alphabet[]]|>, 1000]]
```

creates a nice looking table, with pagination options at the bottom:
[image]

However, when I'm embedding it in a `Manipulate`, the pagination disappears:

```
Dataset`$DatasetTargetRowCount = 10;
Manipulate[
 data[Select[#a >= mina && #b <= maxb &]],
 {{mina, 1}, Range[10]},
 {{maxb, 20}, Range[20]}]
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to add it back? The documentation for `Dataset` mentions symbol `$DatasetTargetRowCount` (used above), which controls the number of output lines, and there is a whole list of internal symbols that Wolfram One's autocomplete indicate are available (see below), but it's not clear if/how to use them, as they are (obviously) not documented.

Any help (esp. from Wolfram Insiders) is much appreciate. I'm on 11.3 if that matters. And if your advice for me is to patiently wait for version 12, I'm cool with it, too!

[image]

Comment: I discovered that setting ``Dataset`$DatasetInteractivity`` to `True`/`False` can enable or disable the pagination *outside* of `Manipulate`, but it doesn't affect the `Manipulate` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that in 12.1, the problem is solved!

```
data = Dataset[
  Table[<|"a" -> RandomInteger[10], "b" -> RandomInteger[20], 
    "c" -> RandomChoice[Alphabet[]]|>, 1000]];
Manipulate[
 Dataset[data[Select[#a >= mina && #b <= maxb &]], 
  MaxItems -> 10], {{mina, 1}, Range[10]}, {{maxb, 20}, Range[20]}]
```

[image]